# Exchange hybrid migration wizard from Windows 2008 First Release

Tags: exchange

I am trying to install the hybrid migration wizard on a first release windows 2008 server and I am at a point were it needs .NET 4.7 which will not install on 2008 first release. Does anyone have a workaround for this? Microsoft compatibility matrix did say it was supported but they may have changed things.

Other than upgrading the 2008 server to R2 or 2012, does anyone have an idea?

Thanks

Comment: According to MS, only .NET Framework 4.6 and below are installable on Windows Server 2008 (with SP2). So I don't think it's possible. - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found out that the Hybrid Configuration Wizard does not have to be run on the exchange server.  I ran it from a Windows 10 Desktop and it setup the hybrid config and transferred my test batch of mailboxes.   So if you are going from a Windows Server 2008 first release with Exchange 2010, your best bet is to install the wizard on a workstation of another server.

kevin

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft .NET Framework: 4.6.2 or later is required to install Hybrid Configuration Wizard. So Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 is at least.